# How to deploy Front end and backend on Plesk

Tags: node.js, deployment, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am trying to deploy my Front-end React and backend Rest api's in node.js, The server is being accessed with plesk dashboard. I was successfully able to deploy my front-end following these steps by **deploying build** and changing root folder https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/

But here I do not find a way to deploy my **backend node.js** rest api on different port as we do in vps via terminal, i couldn't find way to access terminal either.

On Creating subdomain and redoing the same steps to deploy [node.js-plesk](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/)  I get ip **address not found api.domain.digital’s server IP address could not be found.**